# Convergence of zeta Euler product with additional term

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, euler-product

Let's consider the following Euler product ($s=\sigma+it)$:

$$ P(s)=\prod_{p \; \text{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \; e^{-p^{-s}}$$

So for $\sigma>1$, it is clear the product converges and we have:

$$ P(s)=\zeta(s) \prod_{p \; \text{prime}}  e^{-p^{-s}} = \zeta(s) B(s)$$

But for $\frac{1}{2} <\sigma \leq 1$, the product $P(s)$ is also converging (taking the log of $P(s)$ we see it is absolutely convergent),
so on this interval (if $B(s)$ can be analytically continued), then can we write that we have also following relation ?:

$$ P(s)=\prod_{p \; \text{prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \; e^{-p^{-s}} = \zeta(s) B(s)$$

(even if on this interval the Euler product does not converge for $P(s)$ or $\zeta(s)$. We have $P(s)$ and $\zeta(s) B(s)$ which coincide for $\sigma >1$).

I would say no, as the zeros of $\zeta$ seems to disappear in the product... but why exactly the equality does not hold ?

Note: maybe in my example the function $B(s)$ is not optimum because I do not know if it can be prolonged analytically for $\frac{1}{2} <\sigma \leq 1$, but imagine a function that makes the Euler product to converge (same principle as above) and can be prolonged analytically for $\frac{1}{2} <\sigma \leq 1$, then can we say that equality will hold also for $\frac{1}{2} <\sigma \leq 1$.

Comment: If $P(s)$ is indeed analytic for $\frac{1}{2} < \sigma \le 1$ (note the non-strict inequality on the right), then is the definition $B(s) = P(s) / \zeta(s)$ not an analytic continuation of $B(s)$ to that region?

Comment: Yes, I would say you are right.

Comment: Better put, $B(s)$ would be analytic except at the zeroes of $\zeta$ where it has poles

Comment: Yes, you are right. And can we write that $P(s)=\zeta(s) B(s)$ in this strip ? It would mean the zeros of $P(s)$ in this strip are same as Zeta ? Strange for me.

Comment: No, $P$ has no zeroes, while the zeroes of $\zeta$ are cancelled by the poles of $B$: a simple example of this is $\xi$ who is entire and a product of $\zeta$ and $\Gamma$ and some non zero powers and for which the trivial zeroes of $\zeta$ cancel the poles of $\Gamma$

Comment: Ok, I see, clear. Thanks.

Comment: You can add additional exponential factors to increase the convergence range but not sure if you gain much - the usual approach is to use more controllable factors (molifiers) that restrict the zeroes of the result rather than cancel them out together and get estimates for things if interest them